# jQuery get numeric input from all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, jquery-mobile

I want the user to press on a number key while focus is on an input item, and the browser should go to `foo.com/[number]`

this is the code I am using:

```
function isNumberKey(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
    && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.my_input').keypress(function(event){
        if(isNumberKey(event)){
            window.location='foo.com/'+(event.keyCode-48);
        }
   });

});
```

It works on Google Chrome, but Firefox users are getting errors. I also want to implement a mobile version where the user can input the number, and press the "enter" key of the mobile device.

How can I ensure that this will work on all browsers that support javascript?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is the error you are getting on firefox?

Comment: @TimeDead unfortunately my os (ubuntu) is broken so I cannot install software. I will try to browse from someone else's computer asap. So I'm hoping that someone else had already encountered this issue and already knows what the error (and the solution) is :)

Comment: So if I press key 5 (charcode `53`) should the browser go to `foo.com/5` or `foo.com/53`? Note that if I press key 5 on my numpad the charcode is `101`.

Comment: @Moob It should go to foo.com/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your code corrected but I don't think this is really what you're after. Note that charcode returned from the numpad is different from the that of the number-key row.

```js
function isNumberKey(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if ((charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57) || (charCode >= 96 && charCode <= 105)) { //0-9 only (inc numpad)
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='number']").on("keyup",function(evt){
      if(isNumberKey(evt)){
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
            //window.location='foo.com/'+(charCode-48);
            alert('foo.com/'+(charCode-48));//minus 48 wont work if numpad
        }
   });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" value="" />
```

It may be better to just get the `value` of the input instead...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='number']").on("keyup",function(){
        var val = parseInt(this.value);
        this.value="";
        if(val>0){
            alert('foo.com/'+val);
        }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" value="" />
```

Comment: Thanks @Moob, yes value looks better. I will try this and paste the results